# Node.js http-server 2 folders

Tags: node.js

This will create a working `http://127.0.0.1:8080/example-file.html` server:

```
npm install http-server -g
http-server D:\
```

But I wonder if it would be possible to create 1 server for 2 partitions like `D:` and `E:`?

So that the files are accessible like `http://127.0.0.1:8080/d/example-file.html` and `http://127.0.0.1:8080/e/example-file.html`.

(Or some other URL format is also acceptable — this is to circumvent iframes blocked by CORS restrictions — e.g. `window.frames[0].document` will not work even if the second origin has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header set.)

Comment: You can try to create two shortcuts for the disks, name them 'd' and 'e' and then server the folder that you placed the shortcuts

Comment: Just tried this: the shortcuts become 2 downloadable files then and stop being shortcuts. So, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Using [express.static()](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) worked.